# Convenience function for # elements in data.frame, matrix, vector?

Tags: r

Is there a built-in convenience function that returns the number of elements in a data.frame, matrix, or vector?  `length( matrix )` and `length( vector )` work, but `length( data.frame )` returns the number of columns.  `prod( dim( vector ) )` returns 1 always, but works fine with matrix/data.frame.  I'm looking for a single function that works for all three.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think one already exists, so just write your own.  You should only need 2 cases, 1) lists, 2) arrays:

```
elements <- function(x) {
  if(is.list(x)) {
    do.call(sum,lapply(x, elements))
  } else {
    length(x)
  }
}
d <- data.frame(1:10, letters[1:10])
m <- as.matrix(d)
v <- d[,1]
l <- c(d, list(1:5))
L <- list(l, list(1:10))
elements(d)  # data.frame
# [1] 20
elements(m)  # matrix
# [1] 20
elements(v)  # vector
# [1] 10
elements(l)  # list
# [1] 25
elements(L)  # list of lists
# [1] 35
```

Comment: I would not have thought you needed to test for the array case. `length` should return the correct value for matrices and arrays.

Answer (score 5):

What about `length(unlist(whatever))`?

(Note: I just wanted to reply that there's no such function, but suddenly I recalled I just used unlist 30 minutes ago, and that it can be applied to get easy solution! What a coincidence...)

Comment: `unlist(whatever)` may be time-consuming if `whatever` is large.

Comment: @Joshua, nope, I tested it and I get immediate response even for 2*10^7 records (I cannot place more in memory). I think we are sometimes optimizing too much - too much complication for no benefit :-)

Comment: @TomasT. that's probably because you tested it on a vector or matrix, where `unlist` doesn't have to do anything.  Test it on a data.frame (or any other list-type object): `unlist(data.frame(numeric(1e7))`.

Answer (score 1):

My personal 'convenience function' for this is:

```
Rgames: lssize
function(items){
sizes<-sapply(sapply(sapply(sapply(items,get,simplify=F),unlist,simplify=F),as.vector,simplify=F),length)
return(sizes)
    }
```

It works on every 'typeof' variable I could think of.  FWIW, it's part of my toolkit which includes the useful "find only one type of variable in my workspace"  :

```
Rgames: lstype
function(type='closure'){
    inlist<-ls(.GlobalEnv)
    if (type=='function') type <-'closure'
    typelist<-sapply(sapply(inlist,get),typeof)
    return(names(typelist[typelist==type]))
```

}

Comment: Carl - thanks so much!  I think this suffers from the same unlist performance issue that Joshua mentioned?  is your toolkit available to the public?

Comment: SFun: I don't think I've posted all my "toys" anywhere, but certainly I retain no copyright or anything on them.  Take a look at http://witthoft.com/rtools.html in a few days and see if I remembered to put in links for  "mytoys" .  If I haven't, send me an email to remind me.    As to the unlist performance time- I haven't tried it on any gigundo list, so I don't know.

Comment: awesome!  looking forward to checking them out.

Comment: ok, 'mytoys.R' is posted on the above-mentioned web page.  Good luck :-)